# Android Image application OutOfMemory again

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I still dealing with my OutOfMemoryError problem, and now I'm in a hurry because we are reaching the project time limit.

I'm developing for an All-in-one android tablet (1920x1080 resolution)

My application consists on 3 views:

Book Category menu - Book menu (the list of books in the selected category) - Book pages display.

Book category, and book menu, are very similar:
One Horizontal Scroll View, that displays the list of (categories/books) (ImageViews added dynamically for each category/book in category).

When you click in one category, the application takes you to the book menu of that category, and when you click on a book, the application takes you to the book view.

The book view, is a copy of Android image_detail_pager and image_detail_fragment (Android's Displaying bitmaps efficiently Tutorial)

The 3rd screen (Book view), shows 4 images 1920x1080px resolution (full screen)
If I put that images in Android example project, OutOfMemoryError occurs again.

So, if Android's project fails, what can I do in my app?.

The other thing, in Android's example project, it loads the image from Internet, my images are already on disk.

Any ideas?. 
Or I have to switch my application design to a Windows PC with a touch screen monitor and forget about android?.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of Bitmap memory. Can you use smaller images?

Comment: Nope, I have to use full screen for Books.
I'm using the lowest quality possible

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage the `Memory Cache` and the `Disk Cache` for your bitmaps to avoid `OutOfMemoryError`.

[Look at his Google Developer link, Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html). You will find good practices to help you.

And you should also read this:
[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)
[Managing Bitmap Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347314/android-image-application-outofmemory-again)

If you need more info, ask me. I will complet my answer.

Comment: Yann, thanks for your answer. 
I'm basing all my app in that code example. But even in that project, with this images, I still getting OOM.

Comment: Eze, you probably have to many image in memory at the same time. Did you tried to display memory used by every images in your log? Maybe you should close your activity or clear the memory when you open a new book. If you use HD images, the 'weight' of those image in memory is probably too big (even if the image is compressed): 1920px x 1080px x 4bits = ~16M

Comment: Sorry, 1920px x 1080px x 4bits = **~8M**

Comment: Yann, I really don't know what I am doing wrong.. But yes, let's suppose that my images size are about 8M: I have a workflow of 3 activities, one at a time, and I don't need to keep alive the previous activity when I enter to another one. So: Application Start: 1. Load of Categories View (8 images 300x300 aprox) Category selection (Finish() Categories View, startActivity(CategoryDetail) 2. Load of category detail (many images of 300x200 -> PROBLEM) 3. Book selection (Finish() and startActivity(BookDetail) 4. Book detail: The same code that android's example. I dnnow :(

Comment: Eze, is your problem only on "2." when you load many images of 300x200? Did you try the project sample "BitmapFun" on my previous links? (http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/BitmapFun.zip) Maybe it can help you.